# How can I store data from a select tag that displays data from a table from the database Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I want to store the data from another table I pick up from the select tag

The data comes from another model, the Remittent model, and I want to select the name of the remittent and get it's ID in order to store it into the Bills table

```
--Bill Controller:

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Bill;
use App\Models\Remittent;

class BillController extends Controller
{
  public function create(){
        $remittents = Remittent::select('remittent')->get();
        return view('bills.create', compact('remittents'));
    }
}
```

```
--Bill Model:

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bill extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bills';
    protected $fillable = ['number','remittent_id'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function remittent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Remittent::class);
    }
}
```

```
--Remittent Model:

?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Remittent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'remittents';
    protected $fillable = ['remittent'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function bill()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bill::class);
    }
}
```

```
--The view:

@extends('master')
@section('content')
<h2>Add a bill</h2>
@if($errors->all())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
<form action="{{route('bills.store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bill number</label>
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Remittent</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            @foreach($remittents as $remittent)
                <option value="$remittent->id">{{ $remittent->remittent}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add a bill</button>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection
```

The thing is, on the MySql Table the value the store method is expecting is an integer value, and when I select the option from the select tag, its an String value, so I want to know how to get the ID from the remittent table when I select it from the select tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your blade template has an error in the following line:

```
<option value="$remittent->id">{{ $remittent->remittent}}</option>
```

You need to wrap all variable usages in curly braces, no matter if it is something the user sees or if its *invisible* markup. So, just change it to the following:

```
<option value="{{ $remittent->id}} ">{{ $remittent->remittent }}</option>
```

And in your controller, select both, `id` and `remittant`:

```
Remittant::select(['id', 'remittant']) - >get();
```